# AngularJS "ReferenceError: window is not defined" in NodeJS Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug

I'm trying to use Angular module in nodeJS Application with express 4 and jade.

So, for it i did `npm install angular --save` and `var angular = require('angular');` in app.js.

***But It's Throwing an Error***

```
e:\Project\node_modules\angular\angular.js:29016
})(window, document);
   ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Project\node_modules\angular\angular.js:29016:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Project\node_modules\angular\index.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Project\app.js:11:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

**In Reason for this.**

**I'm going to set active status to my sidebar in anjularjs.
Here My Jade File**

```
ul.sidebar-nav(ng-controller="HeaderController")
    // li.sidebar-brand
    li(ng-class="{ active: isActive('/dashboard')}")
        a(href='/dashboard') Dashboard
    li(ng-class="{ active: isActive('/cases')}")
        a(href='/cases') Cases
    li(ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contacts')}")
        a(href='/contacts') Contacts
    li(ng-class="{ active: isActive('/documents')}")
        a(href='/documents') Documents
    li(ng-class="{ active: isActive('/calendar')}")
        a(href='/calendar') Calendar
    li(ng-class="{ active: isActive('/timeline')}")
        a(href='/timeline') Timeline
```

**and here module**

```
function HeaderController($scope, $location) 
{ 
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you expect angular to do, **server side**, in a node.js application?

Comment: Your edits don't seem to have anything to do with what I asked in my comment. One bit of the code you added appears to be some server side code to generate HTML with angular expando-attributes that will be sent to the browser. The other appears to be some code to run client side in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nodejs enviroment there is no window object. There is an "equivalent" for window. Here you can read about it [DOC for Global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global). Angular is for client side development. You are not able to run it on server side.

Comment: agree with you, I got some idea from your comment. Thadam

Comment: @DININDU - please share your solution.

Comment: @SaranshKejriwal Just import js file to your html template as follow `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>` :)